# How to display a number instead of dots with popover description

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm displaying data in `antd` steps in (Dot Style) and on hovering the dot I displayed the data in Popover using react. Code works fine. As I added more steps, It looks clumsy. Here is the working code please give me a suggestion on how to display numbers in place of dot. On hovering the number(in place of Dot) then we display data in Popover.

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      steps: [
        { name: "START", dateTime: "Aug 05, 2019 12:30 PM" },
        {
          name: "RTC complex (PICKUP)",
          dateTime: "12:40 PM - 12:50 PM min(s)"
        },
        {
          name: "Kailasagiri Rope Way (DROP)",
          dateTime: "02:04 PM - 02:50 PM   46min(s)"
        },
        { name: "END", dateTime: "Aug 04, 2019 5:30 PM" }
      ]
    };
  }
  render() {
    const customDot = (dot, props) => {
      const { description, title, index } = props;

      if (description) {
        return (
          <Popover
            content={
              <div style={{ width: "140px", textAlign: "center" }}>
                <p> {title} </p>
                <p> {description} </p>
              </div>
            }
          >
            {dot}
          </Popover>
        );
      }
      return dot;
    };

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Row gutter={16}>
          <Col xs={24}>
            <Steps
              progressDot={(dot, properties) => customDot(dot, properties)}
              current={0}
            >
              {this.state.steps.map((step, index) => (
                <Steps.Step
                  key={index}
                  title={step.name}
                  description={step.dateTime}
                />
              ))}
            </Steps>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the link of my  working code sandbox  example https://codesandbox.io/s/react-steps-f3b0t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `icon` property of `Steps.Step` while adjusting the `placement` property of `Popover`.

That's because you trying to make a "Custom" step with `Popover`.

```js
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    steps: [...]
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Steps style={{ margin: 40 }}>
          {this.state.steps.map((step, index) => (
            <Steps.Step
              key={index}
              title={step.name}
              description={step.dateTime}
              icon={
                <Popover
                  // Choose your placement depending on steps location
                  placement="bottom"
                  content={
                    <div>
                      {step.name}
                      <br />
                      {step.dateTime}
                    </div>
                  }
                >
                  // Change icon to numbers
                  <Button shape="circle" type={index ? 'default' : 'primary'}>
                    {index + 1}
                  </Button>
                </Popover>
              }
            />
          ))}
        </Steps>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit Q-57393663-StepsHoverNumbered]

Comment: Can you please help me with rendering  the steps with out name and description but when we hover the number then we display the name and description in popover.

Comment: so remove the title and descriiption... its basic